# Can Kafka Connect config and offset topics be shared

Tags: apache-kafka

Can the two Apacke Kafka Connect metadata topics, `config.storage.topic` and `offset.storage.topic`, be shared safely between two or more separate Kafka Connect clusters?

While the documentation states for each that:

> This must be the same for all workers with the same `group.id`.

It's not clear from the documentation whether these topics need to essentially be owned by single Kafka Connect clusters.

Broadly speaking, I can see that my connect `group.id` *could* be used as a prefix for the items in the topic, but it's not clear whether it is, nor whether it's safe to rely on as a way to separate out Connect clusters from each other's metadata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each cluster needs its own dedicated topics.

If you have multiple Kafka Connect clusters trying to use the same config/offset/status topics—even with different `group.id` set—you'll get a ton of errors and/or unexpected behaviour from Kafka Connect.

Comment: Interesting. I would have guessed otherwise. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah - it seems a shame it can't share based on uniqueness with `group.id`, but I can confirm from having been burnt with it that it definitely doesn't work :)

Comment: Additionally, if you consume from the offset topic using the console consumer, you can see that the message is formatted as: {"offset":1234} which unfortunately does not contain group.id or anything else useful.